# How is possible to open website inside facebook mobile app like buzzfeed?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, reactjs, share, facebook-social-plugins

I see buzzfeed did some changes on their website, and now buzzfeed URLs shared on facebook are shown as below

Links shared on facebook opened inside facebook like new window. It doesn't requests any other browser or facebook apps browser. Page loads very fast. How it's possible to implement? What technology uses Buzzfeed for it?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The feature is called **Instant Articles** and is available for publishers, it seems more like people publishing the articles on their platform.

see: https://instantarticles.fb.com/